# Volume of a rectangular prism when the prism has walls

Tags: geometry, volume

An esky has a height of 50cm, a width of 25cm and a length of 75cm. The walls of the esky are 4cm thick on each side (including the lid). If it is filled with cold water, how many litres will it hold?

The answer is apparently 236cm², and apparently you have to subtract 8 from the height, length and width. I don't really understand why.

Comment: Try to visualize the column of water that would be contained. Its dimensions can be deducted from the given information. If it's a rectangle, it's easy to calculate its volume once you have the dimensions.

Comment: When I "subtract $8$ from the height, length and width" I get $(50-8)(25-8)(75-8) = 47838,$ and converting to liters gives $47.838$ liters. No idea where the $236$ came from. If you still don't understand, I suggest you edit the question to show the complete working (as far as you know it or can guess it) and anything else that you know about the problem.

Comment: You will probably need to show some formulas or equations; use MathJax to make these readable to other people. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show why we drop 8 cm on each dimension, let's sketch out one side of the esky*:

[image]

(* Not entirely to scale...)

The surface area of this side is 75x50 $cm^2$. The blue area is (75 - 4 - 4) x (50 - 4 - 4) = 67 x 42 $cm^2$. Don't mind the orange areas, you're not subtracting them twice. You can see that a little more clearly when we cheat a  bit and move the blue area:

[image]

This is done on a 2D-plane to show the principle, but it holds for 3D volumes as well.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I AM THE MOST DUMB PERSON EVER BUT THANK YOU I UNDERSTAND